# How to find cheapest one-day return flight from specific airports to anywhere?

Tags: air-travel, transit

I want to find a cheapest one-day return flight from one of two specific airports to anywhere. It has to be a Star Alliance airline. And it has to be this year. 
I don't even need to leave the airport. I can hop in the return plane straight away.

Google has almost the perfect search. But I either have to stay for a weekend or enter specific date manually:
https://www.google.com/flights#flt=/m/02z0j,MUC..2019-10-26*./m/02z0j,MUC.2019-10-26;c:EUR;e:1;a:STAR_ALLIANCE*STAR_ALLIANCE;ls:we;sd:1;t:e

I don't know if the url is valid but here's an example of a search for specific date. I'd like to have this search for a 1 day trip in a whole month instead.
On the PC I can filter also by the price.

Comment: Skyscanner is another one that lets you do everything but one part of this. You can pick a specific day, put X airport to anywhere and search but you then can only filter by airline after the results come in so its not effective for what you want. Simply clarifying this before others can make the same comment claiming it can be done there.

Comment: @Uciebila I can filter by airline after I pick a location, I don't wanna do that